# org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils vs org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

Tags: java, apache-commons

Please, help, I have broken my head over this:

So here is a scenario:
I pulled a project from central repo
and it uses "commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar" in its class path
In one of the java classes - let's say "classA"
it has the following

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
```

and in production, it compiles just fine.  But not in my environment (in eclipse and in InteliJ).  **This is a real issue I have.  The fact that it does not compile, but "officially", I can't change the "ClassA" to use different import !!**  I know how to make it compile, but I won't be allowed to commit the change, since it works in central builds.

It will ONLY work in my environment IF I CHANGE the import statement to

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;
```

**lang3** !!!

in the build.xml I see it using

```
<fileset dir="${webinf.lib}">
      <include name="commons-lang3-3.1.jar"/>
</fileset>
```

I am checking all over, and in the only location pointed by **${webinf.lib}** it is
**commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar**
I can't figure out where or how to find that **'commons-lang3-3.1.jar'**

Search by name, does not give anything